# A variable Y that should approach another variable X over time

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a variable X that is increasing over time (each 500ms). I have also a variable Y with random intial value. I have 10 steps (50ms between each step), in these steps Y should go closer to X value but fluently. In the final step we should have Y = X but fluently over these 10 steps.

I tried this code below but I am still far away from the goal of the final step which Y = X, I feel like i should use some mathematical series but I donno how to do it

```js
// A variable X that is increasing over time (each 500ms)
var x = 10
var intervalX = setInterval(function() {
x += 1;
console.log("x = " + x)
}, 500);

//A variable Y with random intial value,
var y = 231;
var step =0;
var intervalY = setInterval(function() {
var distanceYX = (x - y) / 10
y += distanceYX
console.log("y = " + y)
step++;
  if(step==10) {
    clearInterval(intervalY)
  }
}, 50);
```

PS : Y can be higher or lower than X

Comment: Define "fluently".

Comment: for instance linearly,

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's called a mathematical *sequence* or *progression* and not a series (which is the partial sum of such a sequence) - that's probably the terminology confusion :)

If you want it to reach it *linearly* it's called an arithmetic sequence, if you want to reach it *exponentially* it's called a geometric sequence.

You know A(1) (the first term) which is X
You know A(n) (the last term) which is Y
You know n - which is 10

You can plug them into the formulas here for [geometric sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) or [arithmetic sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression).